# Can't Populate Lists in Dictionary of Empty Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am using defaultdict to initialize a dictionary of empty lists to be populated.

```
from collections import defaultdict
performance_deltas = defaultdict(list)
```

and I am attempting to populate the lists by appending to the lists.

```
def add_data_to_Golden(data_set):
    performance_deltas = defaultdict(list)
    for build in data_set:
        for workload in data_set[build]:
            performance_deltas[workload].append(data_set[build][workload])
    return performance_deltas
```

`data_set` is a dictionary of dictionaries used to compile data from various CSVs. The desired result is for `performance_deltas` to be a dict of lists with each list gaining additional values so it becomes a dictionary with the workload as the key and a list of the values from each build for that particular workload. Each build in `data_set` has the same workload keys. `add_data_to_Golden` is only being called once within main.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what is happening? E.G. a stripped down code segment and it's output

Comment: That should work just fine.  Are you sure `workload` remains constant?

Answer (score 0):

If *data* is a list, then you should use [list.extend() instead of list.append()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). extend() will append all items from the given list to the target list.

Otherwise, I don't believe multiple appends to the same *workload* doesn't increase the list.

Comment: Data is a single value in this case

Comment: @CoryI, then you need to paste more of your code,  especially the code about*workload*, so that people here can get the context before *guessing* the cause?

Comment: @Coryl, sorry I'm not able to spot what's wrong with your code :(